# Condition not meeting in c

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

For some reason this condition is not passing as true even tho the variable watch is showing var equal.[image]

```
    if(arr[r1][1] != NULL) {
        t_plat = arr[r1][1];
        t_ver = arr[r1][2];


if((arr[r2][1] == t_plat) && (arr[r2][2] == t_ver))
```

Comment: You are comparing the addresses of the strings (which are not equal)  To compare the contents of the strings use strcmp() from string.h

Comment: Of course they aren't equal. You compare pointers, and can clearly see that `0xb01a70 != 0xb01770`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah , any help on how to accomplish strcmp() function ? should i get 2 extra char variables to move pointer values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see yourself from the screenshot the object `arr[r2][1]` stores value `0xb01a70` while the object `t_plat` stores value `0xb01770`.

Thus if you compare the values stored in these objects like

```
if((arr[r2][1] == t_plat) )
```

you will get `false` without doubts. The values are unequal each other.

What are these values? They are pointers to first characters of strings. If you want to compare the strings themselves pointed to by the pointers you have to use standard C function `strcmp` declared in header `<string.h>`.

Thus you should write

```
if( strcmp( arr[r2][1], t_plat ) == 0 && strcmp( arr[r2][2], t_ver ) == 0 )
```

Comment: @d3l Did I said that they are pointers? I have not understand your comment and why you down-voted my correct answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow What if I want to make of of these equal to NULL ?eg: arr[r1][0] = NULL; arr[r1][1] = NULL; arr[r1][2] = NULL; would these make it equal to NULL or not , if not then what is the correct way of doing it ?

Comment: @Fenomatik Why not? You can set pointers to NULL. However you should do this caution. If a pointer pointes to a dynamically allocated memory you should at first free it before assigning the pointer with NULL. Otherwise there can be a memory leak.

Comment: @Fenomatik And yes you can compare pointers with NULL. If a pointer assigned with NULL then it will be equal to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare strings in C like in any other language, because in C a string is a **pointer**.

So you are not comparing the value but the address of the strings which are not the same.

To check if two strings are equal use the `strcasecmp` or `strcmp` functions from `<string.h>`.

Example:

```
if (strcmp(arr[r2][1], t_pat) == 0) {
    // arr[r2][1] and t_pat are equal by value
}
```